# Share CPU equally between users (not processes) in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, process, user

Can I share the CPU equally between users (not processes), in Debian? For example, I have two users, I want each to be able to use 50% of the CPU - even if one user has one process running and the other one has 9 processes. By default Debian shares the CPU between processes, so that if 10 processes are running, each has 10% of the CPU. Can we change that?

P.S.: I know that this might be easier in CentOS or RedHat (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu_and_memory-use_case.html) and that Debian 8 (jessie) switched to systemd and that with systemd it should be easier to create cgroups. But I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Thank you!